# Web Audio API AudioBufferSourceNode detune

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I've created an AudioBufferSourceNode: `var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();`. Next I load the buffer via XHR with a track from Soundcloud.  I can get all methods to function properly and can adjust most of the attributes like `loop`, `buffer`, `playbackRate.value` etc.  It says in the documentation that `detune.value` is another attribute that can be adjusted.  However when I try it, expecting it to change the pitch of the track, nothing happens.  The console tells me that `source.detune` is undefined when it should be and object if I'm not mistaken.  I was able to get the detune to work perfectly on an Oscillator but not a buffer loaded via XHR.  So is the detune attribute only limited to certain types of AudioBufferSourceNodes (or buffers) and Oscillators, or is there another way to go about changing the pitch of a track without adjusting the playbackRate?

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, you're using Chrome stable.  Detune is fairly new, and hasn't made it into stable yet.  It works in Chrome Canary (and Firefox).